# Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: excel, database-connection, connection-string, powerquery

When we refresh query in Excel 2016 we get:

```
Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1 provider is not registered on the local machine
```

Connection string has this in it:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;...etc...
```

Please let me know what else you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the data source permission settings needed to be refreshed, mine was working happily for a long time on a machine, one day to the next the permission disappeared, re-applied the permission and and works again from within VBA.

PaCool